# Make right hand column fill remaining space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple flexbox layout...

```css
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    width:100%;
}

.left {
    background:red;
}

.left img {
    padding:20px;
}

.right {
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="left">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff">
</div>

<div class="right">
Right content
</div>

</div>
```

How do I make the right column fill the remaining space?

Answer (score 0):

you can add `flex: 1;` to `.right`

```css
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row
    width:100%;
}

.left {
    background:red;
}

.left img {
    padding:20px;
}

.right {
  background:green;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="left">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff">
</div>

<div class="right">
Right content
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about flex-grow?

```css
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row
    width:100%;
}

.left {
    background:red;
}

.left img {
    padding:20px;
}

.right {
    background:green;
    flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="left">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff">
</div>

<div class="right">
Right content
</div>

</div>
```